# Query to unify repeating elements and their fields in common

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, database

I would like to know if anyone can help me. I have the following:

- Collection T_WORKS
- Collection T_WORKERS
- Collection T_WORKSTATION

In the Collection T_WORKS I have objects of the style:

```
{
    "_id": "0084e515 ...",
    "Description": "Milling machine",
    "worker" : {
        "$ Ref": "T_WORKER",
        "$ Id": "6183d4bc ..."
    },
    "workstation" : {
        "$ Ref": "T_WORKSTATION",
        "$ Id": ObjectId ("567bbcbd ...")
    }
}
```

This collection can have several objects with the same worker, but different client, because for example: somebody can be a chapist, but also a mechanic, then he would have two records in T_WORKS with the same reference to T_WORKER.

Now, I want to create a query that returns me something like: Each of the workers there are, and all the jobs in which they work (which can be 0 or up to 10).

I have tried with some type of query: (...). Aggregate ([{$ group: {_ id: "$ worker", posts: {$ push: "$workstation"}}}]), it looks similar to what I want (worker, and their workstation list), but not all the records that should ...

Any ideas?

I want something similar to:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId(..),
    "clients" : [ 
        {
            "id" : ObjectId("...")
        }, 
        {
            "id" : ObjectId("...")
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You actually cannot have `$` in the field names. So what you claim you have is not actually possible, and the names must **actually** be quoted in some way that is not being shown. For the same reason you cannot have output that includes a `$` in the name. This is actually "reserved" in MongoDB, and hence why it is disallowed for other use.

Comment: You might possibly be referring to what is actually `DBRef` data. This is just as bad and should in fact be removed completely and replaced with standard `ObjectId` references and handling the collection data differently. Aggregation functions simply do not support `DBRef` at all.